# GNU Coreutils: true

Tags: gnu, utility

Зачем нужна утилита true?

Вот, что выдает man:

```
       true - do nothing, successfully
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что утилита "ничего не делает"? Но тогда зачем она?

Comment: Для того же, для чего и в других языках `while true; do echo "test"; done`

Comment: Она предназначена для того, чтобы другие команды (`if`, `while` и т.п.) использовали ее *код завершения* (его также иначе называют *код возврата*)